# Getting the optimize flag to work on a local GraphHopper Routing Service

Tags: graphhopper, jsprit

I have setup a local GraphHopper service on a local server and it works as advertised.  I can pass it a set of points via rest, and get back a happy little JSON file of directions and an encoded route.  Of course, "out of the box" the routing API is missing a toggle available in the paid Routing API service via graphhopper.com, and that is the optimize=true/false flag.  This little addition will not only route between your passed points, but when set to true will also re-order them into the most optimal route.

Now I imagine to get this additional functionality one needs to somehow "bake in" some level of jsprit code.  My level of understanding of Java and compiling code however is woefully inadequate here.  Looking over numerous jsprit sites the best help I can find is "look at the source code for examples".  Is there any sort of guide for building jsprit into the standard graphhopper JAR file, or does anyone know of any pre-built JARs out there with this functionality already built in?  it's probably a long shot, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I really doubt you'd find this. The closest might be `ODL Studio` source code, but that's overblown for your needs. The honest answer, I think it's going to be one of those where you brute-force your way into Java or just pay one of them to do it for you and get something professional off the bat. What they give on Apache license is already huge and commercial software in this area is _extortionate_ in comparison. I have no affiliation with either team, and know how to make your setup, but I suspect many would feel like me and not want to post such guides freely to undercut them.

Comment: Thanks, and that's understandable.  It's the links between the disparate bits of open source routing software that is the value-add for the commercial entities out there.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something before presenting all options to our decision-makers.  I believe our management will prefer to pay the relatively low subscription rate to use a pre-built service rather than to have me re-invent the wheel.

Comment: That's fair enough, you have to make your case. Random Person on the Internet's opinion is perhaps not so strong but I have had the displeasure of speaking to 7 or 8 routing companies and their _capabilities_ do not exceed the two combined (whether they were faster, I don't know). For those companies, a lot of the cost goes on fancy integration (Apps and GUIs etc)and it's much easier to hire for people that do that kind of thing than an expert in vehicle routing.